# Paypal subscription error: The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using Paypal website payment standard to subscription for my site. Here is the variables passing in Paypal which I dumped. I'm passing this values to '**https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr**' using post method.

```
Field Name     Value
a3             19.99 
business       [email]
cancel_return  http://example.com
cmd            _xclick-subscriptions 
currency_code  USD 
custom         This is custom 
invoice        [invoice]
item_name      Account
item_number    21
no_note        1 
no_shipping    1 
notify_url     http://example.com/ipn
p3             1 
return         http://example.com/success 
rm             2 
sra            1 
src            1 
srt            1 
t3             D
```

Now the matter is this that the Paypal shows a **error** :

> The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid.

Please review the link and try again. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: here is a sample code from my app
http://pastebin.com/XxHuTK4V

Comment: Perhaps, try valid cancel/notify/return URLs?

Comment: they are OK. correctly entered

Comment: You mean to say, you didn't use http://example.com?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use srt = 1.  Use srt to set the number of times the subscription should renew.  1 doesn't make any sense because a recurring payment that occurs one time is not a recurring payment.  Just leave srt off if it is 1, and it will default to recur until someone cancels it.